# Matplotlib with JSON files

Tags: python, json, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to combine two sources of code with no avail.  I am using the default finance2.py matplotlib example (listed below) with json files (also listed below).  the "finance.fetch_historical_yahoo" section of the code pulls data from a .csv via yahoo, and puts it into a numpy array.  The issue is, I don't need yahoo's data to be translated, I need the JSON data to be translated in a manner that is readable by the matplotlib library.

finance2.py:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.finance as finance
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
import json #to load json libraries for json data

startdate = datetime.date(2006,1,1)
today = enddate = datetime.date.today()
ticker = 'SPY'


fh = finance.fetch_historical_yahoo(ticker, startdate, enddate) #would like this call to be json
# a numpy record array with fields: date, open, high, low, close, volume, adj_close)

r = mlab.csv2rec(fh); fh.close()
r.sort()


def moving_average(x, n, type='simple'):
    """
    compute an n period moving average.

    type is 'simple' | 'exponential'

    """
    x = np.asarray(x)
    if type=='simple':
        weights = np.ones(n)
    else:
        weights = np.exp(np.linspace(-1., 0., n))

    weights /= weights.sum()


    a =  np.convolve(x, weights, mode='full')[:len(x)]
    a[:n] = a[n]
    return a

def relative_strength(prices, n=14):
    """
    compute the n period relative strength indicator
    http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:glossary_r#relativestrengthindex
    http://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/rsi.asp
    """

    deltas = np.diff(prices)
    seed = deltas[:n+1]
    up = seed[seed>=0].sum()/n
    down = -seed[seed<0].sum()/n
    rs = up/down
    rsi = np.zeros_like(prices)
    rsi[:n] = 100. - 100./(1.+rs)

    for i in range(n, len(prices)):
        delta = deltas[i-1] # cause the diff is 1 shorter

        if delta>0:
            upval = delta
            downval = 0.
        else:
            upval = 0.
            downval = -delta

        up = (up*(n-1) + upval)/n
        down = (down*(n-1) + downval)/n

        rs = up/down
        rsi[i] = 100. - 100./(1.+rs)

    return rsi

def moving_average_convergence(x, nslow=26, nfast=12):
    """
    compute the MACD (Moving Average Convergence/Divergence) using a fast and slow exponential moving avg'
    return value is emaslow, emafast, macd which are len(x) arrays
    """
    emaslow = moving_average(x, nslow, type='exponential')
    emafast = moving_average(x, nfast, type='exponential')
    return emaslow, emafast, emafast - emaslow


plt.rc('axes', grid=True)
plt.rc('grid', color='0.75', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5)

textsize = 9
left, width = 0.1, 0.8
rect1 = [left, 0.7, width, 0.2]
rect2 = [left, 0.3, width, 0.4]
rect3 = [left, 0.1, width, 0.2]


fig = plt.figure(facecolor='white')
axescolor  = '#f6f6f6'  # the axes background color

ax1 = fig.add_axes(rect1, axisbg=axescolor)  #left, bottom, width, height
ax2 = fig.add_axes(rect2, axisbg=axescolor, sharex=ax1)
ax2t = ax2.twinx()
ax3  = fig.add_axes(rect3, axisbg=axescolor, sharex=ax1)



### plot the relative strength indicator
prices = r.adj_close
rsi = relative_strength(prices)
fillcolor = 'darkgoldenrod'

ax1.plot(r.date, rsi, color=fillcolor)
ax1.axhline(70, color=fillcolor)
ax1.axhline(30, color=fillcolor)
ax1.fill_between(r.date, rsi, 70, where=(rsi>=70), facecolor=fillcolor, edgecolor=fillcolor)
ax1.fill_between(r.date, rsi, 30, where=(rsi<=30), facecolor=fillcolor, edgecolor=fillcolor)
ax1.text(0.6, 0.9, '>70 = overbought', va='top', transform=ax1.transAxes, fontsize=textsize)
ax1.text(0.6, 0.1, '<30 = oversold', transform=ax1.transAxes, fontsize=textsize)
ax1.set_ylim(0, 100)
ax1.set_yticks([30,70])
ax1.text(0.025, 0.95, 'RSI (14)', va='top', transform=ax1.transAxes, fontsize=textsize)
ax1.set_title('%s daily'%ticker)

### plot the price and volume data
dx = r.adj_close - r.close
low = r.low + dx
high = r.high + dx

deltas = np.zeros_like(prices)
deltas[1:] = np.diff(prices)
up = deltas>0
ax2.vlines(r.date[up], low[up], high[up], color='black', label='_nolegend_')
ax2.vlines(r.date[~up], low[~up], high[~up], color='black', label='_nolegend_')
ma20 = moving_average(prices, 20, type='simple')
ma200 = moving_average(prices, 200, type='simple')

linema20, = ax2.plot(r.date, ma20, color='blue', lw=2, label='MA (20)')
linema200, = ax2.plot(r.date, ma200, color='red', lw=2, label='MA (200)')


last = r[-1]
s = '%s O:%1.2f H:%1.2f L:%1.2f C:%1.2f, V:%1.1fM Chg:%+1.2f' % (
    today.strftime('%d-%b-%Y'),
    last.open, last.high,
    last.low, last.close,
    last.volume*1e-6,
    last.close-last.open )
t4 = ax2.text(0.3, 0.9, s, transform=ax2.transAxes, fontsize=textsize)

props = font_manager.FontProperties(size=10)
leg = ax2.legend(loc='center left', shadow=True, fancybox=True, prop=props)
leg.get_frame().set_alpha(0.5)


volume = (r.close*r.volume)/1e6  # dollar volume in millions
vmax = volume.max()
poly = ax2t.fill_between(r.date, volume, 0, label='Volume', facecolor=fillcolor, edgecolor=fillcolor)
ax2t.set_ylim(0, 5*vmax)
ax2t.set_yticks([])


### compute the MACD indicator
fillcolor = 'darkslategrey'
nslow = 26
nfast = 12
nema = 9
emaslow, emafast, macd = moving_average_convergence(prices, nslow=nslow, nfast=nfast)
ema9 = moving_average(macd, nema, type='exponential')
ax3.plot(r.date, macd, color='black', lw=2)
ax3.plot(r.date, ema9, color='blue', lw=1)
ax3.fill_between(r.date, macd-ema9, 0, alpha=0.5, facecolor=fillcolor, edgecolor=fillcolor)


ax3.text(0.025, 0.95, 'MACD (%d, %d, %d)'%(nfast, nslow, nema), va='top',
         transform=ax3.transAxes, fontsize=textsize)

#ax3.set_yticks([])
# turn off upper axis tick labels, rotate the lower ones, etc
for ax in ax1, ax2, ax2t, ax3:
    if ax!=ax3:
        for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
            label.set_visible(False)
    else:
        for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
            label.set_rotation(30)
            label.set_horizontalalignment('right')

    ax.fmt_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')



class MyLocator(mticker.MaxNLocator):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        mticker.MaxNLocator.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return mticker.MaxNLocator.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

# at most 5 ticks, pruning the upper and lower so they don't overlap
# with other ticks
#ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(5, prune='both'))
#ax3.yaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(5, prune='both'))

ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(MyLocator(5, prune='both'))
ax3.yaxis.set_major_locator(MyLocator(5, prune='both'))

plt.show()
```

.json file:

```
{
        "instrument" : "EUR_USD",
        "granularity" : "D",
        "candles" : [
                {
                        "time" : "2014-02-17T22:00:00Z",
                        "openMid" : 1.259445,
                        "highMid" : 1.259955,
                        "lowMid" : 1.251825,
                        "closeMid" : 1.257955,
                        "volume" : 61184,
                        "complete" : true
                },
                {
                        "time" : "2014-02-18T22:00:00Z",
                        "openMid" : 1.257975,
                        "highMid" : 1.259955,
                        "lowMid" : 1.251825,
                        "closeMid" : 1.252945,
                        "volume" : 67528,
                        "complete" : false
                }
        ]
}
```

I'm not even exactly looking for a definite answer, even a point in the right direction would be extremely helpful at this point in time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The line below the the `fetch_historical_yahoo` tells you exactly what your data should look like. So, what have you tried? Show us some code (only the relevant parts) where you attempt to convert the json input to a numpy record array.

Comment: reading json you should start with json.load() http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load

Comment: There is _way_ too much code here now.  Very few people are willing to wade through that much code unrelated to your problem.  Please reduce this to the _minimal_ amount of code needed to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer - it shows how to unpack the json into a list of rows (row_wise) or columns (col_wise).

```
import json
import numpy as np
# json embedded here, but could be read in from text file
json_string = """{
        "instrument" : "EUR_USD",
        "granularity" : "D",
        "candles" : [
                {
                        "time" : "2014-02-17T22:00:00Z",
                        "openMid" : 1.259445,
                        "highMid" : 1.259955,
                        "lowMid" : 1.251825,
                        "closeMid" : 1.257955,
                        "volume" : 61184,
                        "complete" : true
                },
                {
                        "time" : "2014-02-18T22:00:00Z",
                        "openMid" : 1.257975,
                        "highMid" : 1.259955,
                        "lowMid" : 1.251825,
                        "closeMid" : 1.252945,
                        "volume" : 67528,
                        "complete" : false
                }
        ]
       }"""

candles = json.loads(json_string)['candles']
col_heads = ['time', 'openMid', 'highMid', 'lowMid', 'closeMid', 'volume']
f = lambda c: [c[col] for col in col_heads]
row_wise = [col_heads[:]]
row_wise.extend([f(candle) for candle in candles])
for row in row_wise: print row
print
col_wise = zip(*row_wise)
for col in col_wise: print col
```

What remains is to construct a numpy recarray: which is what mlab.csv2rec() yields. This is left as an exercise for the numpy gurus (which I ain't! ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can use pandas to solve this problem more concisely. Here's the relevant info for solving your problem. Sorry, I don't have time to customize all the code to your specific use case. Let me know if you revisit this, and would like me to.

From [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html)

```
>>> data = [{'state': 'Florida',
...          'shortname': 'FL',
...          'info': {
...               'governor': 'Rick Scott'
...          },
...          'counties': [{'name': 'Dade', 'population': 12345},
...                      {'name': 'Broward', 'population': 40000},
...                      {'name': 'Palm Beach', 'population': 60000}]},
...         {'state': 'Ohio',
...          'shortname': 'OH',
...          'info': {
...               'governor': 'John Kasich'
...          },
...          'counties': [{'name': 'Summit', 'population': 1234},
...                       {'name': 'Cuyahoga', 'population': 1337}]}]
>>> from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
>>> result = json_normalize(data, 'counties', ['state', 'shortname',
...                                           ['info', 'governor']])
>>> result
         name  population info.governor    state shortname
0        Dade       12345    Rick Scott  Florida        FL
1     Broward       40000    Rick Scott  Florida        FL
2  Palm Beach       60000    Rick Scott  Florida        FL
3      Summit        1234   John Kasich     Ohio        OH
4    Cuyahoga        1337   John Kasich     Ohio        OH
```

Now you can use a [pandas dataframe to visualize the data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html).

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [2]: ts = pandas.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))

In [3]: ts = ts.cumsum()

In [4]: ts.plot()
Out[4]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x1120939d0>
```